# Only dummy output and no soundcards found on Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo, alsa, soundcard

I've really tried everything and I'm begging for your help reader :)

I've re-installed my kernel, followed every possible guide on internet and I still can't make my speakers, headphones or any device other than Dummy output appear under "Sound", alsamixer or (sudo) aplay -l

Currently running 16.04 in a Lenovo Y50-70 (this issue existed since 15.10 though)

I've provided hopefully all needed feedback [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/292286)

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
snd_hda_intel: `2' invalid for parameter `beep_mode'
```

The driver refuses to load because there is an invalid setting for its `beep_mode` parameter.

It should not be necessary to make any customizations to any files in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.